# PostgreSQL timestamp query failure

Tags: javascript, postgresql, timestamp

I have a query that runs fine locally but when released to my stage environment on Heroku the query fails with

```
Error Occurred { error: operator does not exist: character varying > timestamp without time zone
```

I populate a field `kick_off TIMESTAMP` with some JS

```
const fixtureDate = new Date();
const kick_off new Date(fixtureDate.getTime() - (fixtureDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)).toISOString();
```

Now already I am questioning myself over this as we can see a timezone.

The part of the query that fails in staging (but passes locally) is

```
AND kick_off > NOW()-interval '2 hour'
```

I guess this has to do with the way I'm storing my timestamp or the query itself? I have also tried

```
AND kick_off > NOW()::timestamp -interval '2 hour'
```

But that fails as well.

Comment: `kick_off` is somehow passed as a `varchar` value, which is weird. I can't tell why because I don't know Javascript. Try to pass it as `timestamp` or `text` or (if you cannot do that), change the query to `CAST (kick_off AS timestamp) > now()::timestamp - INTERVAL '2 hours'`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe that seems to have worked, that's great, thank you. I did try casting earlier but must have done it incorrectly. Out of interest are there any query performance issues with using CAST ?